# Jquery/css long multi level menu with auto scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, prototype

I want to create `multi level menu with auto scroll`. I already have 
[multi level menu](https://jsfiddle.net/eoqunpvd/). But menu has long drop down list which I want to covert in auto scroll(on mouse move) [like this](https://css-tricks.com/examples/LongDropdowns/).

If any `JS/CSS` expert can help me with running `Jsfiddle` then it would be really great help.

**P.S** : If hover event needed for auto scroll then we can use click even to open sub menu list instead of hover.

Comment: What do you mean by auto scroll? Can you explain your question?

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/examples/LongDropdowns/ which has menu with mouse move (auto scroll), which I want to add in my Jsfiddle to avoid long drop down.

Comment: I guess you're not planing to use this nav in touch devices, otherwise how will you hover in those devices?

Comment: Yes, for touch device I don't need auto move.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I got another good library ([smartmenus](https://www.smartmenus.org/about/themes/#demos-gallery)) which fulfill the same requirement

Thanks to Smartmenus.